# Can I choose to cast a spell with a reduced area of effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

I have little understanding of the rules and systems of 5th Edition, as I have never played myself.

Are you able to cast area-of-effect spells such as *silence* or *darkness* on a smaller (or significantly smaller) area than normal?

For example, could a Way of Shadow monk cast *silence* in a 3-foot radius around their feet to run silently (even though the standard radius of the spell is 20 feet)?

Answer (score 17):

### No, you can't

Unfortunately, [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret). They have a fixed area of effect, unless they say otherwise - if they do, usually they include "up to x feet" instead of "x feet".

For example, *[wall of fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire)* spell description says

> You can make the wall up to 60 feet long, 20 feet high, and 1 foot thick, or a ringed wall up to 20 feet in diameter, 20 feet high, and 1 foot thick.

so you can make the wall shorter or smaller (in case ringed wall).

---

The [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spell description says:

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range **to fill a 15-foot-radius** sphere for the duration.

The description of the [*silence*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) spell says:

> For the duration, no sound can be created within or pass through **a 20-foot-radius sphere** centered on a point you choose within range.

Both don't say "up to", so you can't reduce the area of effect of the spells.

---

*Silence* area of effect won't move once cast, so your scenario casting *silence* around your shoes to move sneakily won't work well, because the silenced area won't stick to your shoes. *Darkness* however, can be cast onto an object, so you can cast darkness on an object and put it within a box, and only opens it when you need the darkness.

At most you can only position the area to exclude your allies, like targetting higher or farther etc. Remember that most spells require you to have line of sight to the center of the area of effect.

---

As an alternative to *darkness*, you can use *dark star*, a spell from Explorer's Guide to Wildemount. This spell acts both as *darkness* and *silence* combined with flexible ***up to*** 40 feet radius. It is a 8th-level spell and still static, so not really a substitute. (Thanks **user68fd**!)